# SubSonic and MS SQL Server Compact - Data Provider

Tags: subsonic, subsonic3, sql-server-ce

I developing new application and I would like using SubSonic and SQL Server Compact.

But when I run my simple app (for trying SubSonic) I get exception *"Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider.  It may not be installed."*

Anyone have some advice for me, how solve this?

I have reference to System.Data.SqlServerCe

---

**UPDATE**

I downloaded SubSonic latest source code and all code about SQL CE is in comments. I uncomment, but I get same exception.

- [DbDataProvider.cs](http://github.com/subsonic/SubSonic-3.0/blob/3f5623aabbd770eff8178f4ae1fb94e26df8c4c5/SubSonic.Core/DataProviders/DbDataProvider.cs)

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: SQL Server CE is supported in SubSonic 2.2 but not in 3. See the [docs](http://subsonicproject.com/docs/Supported_Databases) for more details.

SQL Server CE is not supported at the moment. Someone is apparently working on it but I don't know how far the work on the template has progressed:

http://github.com/subsonic/SubSonic-3.0/issues/unreads#issue/17