# Using Subsonic 2.2 on Windows Mobile 5 with SQL Server CE 3.5

Tags: windows-mobile, subsonic, sql-server-ce

I have seen comments stating that Subsonic currently does nt support MS SQL Server CE ([SubSonic and MS SQL Server Compact - Data Provider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1130863/subsonic-and-ms-sql-server-compact-data-provider)). The link provided is for Subsonic 3.

So my question is, does Subsonic 2.2 support MS SQL Server CE? And if so, is there any documentation on how to use sonic.exe to generate Subsonic's classes and controllers from the database file?

Answer (score 2):

SubSonic 3 does not have templates for SQL CE yet, however 2.2 does support CE. See [here](http://subsonicproject.com/docs/Supported_Databases) for more details. You should be able to follow the standard setup example [here](http://subsonicproject.com/docs/Setting_up_SubSonic_2.x) to get started, although obviously you'll need a CE specific connection string.