# Does SubSonic 3.0 SimpleRepository support SQL Server Compact Edition?

Tags: subsonic, subsonic3, sql-server-ce

Can someone confirm one way or the other if SubSonic 3.0's SimpleRepository supports SQL Server CE (Compact Edition)? I tried it and failed but I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong or if it's not supposed to work.

I'm finding conflicting information online. The [SubSonic documentation page](http://subsonicproject.com/docs/Supported_Databases) says that SQL Server CE *is* supported in SubSonic 3.0. However this (fairly recent) [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1130863/subsonic-and-ms-sql-server-compact-data-provider) says that it *isn't* supported

So which is it? If it is supposed to work, does anyone happen to have a pointer to some working code so I can figure out what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

We use System.Data.Common and from what I understand SQLCE understands System.Data.Common - you just have to be sure you specify that driver in your connection string (and I don't know what that is).

We don't have any T4's built for it yet, but for SimpleQuery it should "just work". What's the error?

Comment: I had to do some experimenting, but I think I got right connection string information:

     connectionString="Data Source=test.sdf; Persist Security Info=False;"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.3.5"

The exception I'm getting is a System.NotSupportedException ("Specified method is not supported.") in ANSISchemaGenerator.cs in GetTableFromDb() and it's the line that calls scope.Connection.GetSchema().

Some googling shows me that other people have had issues with GetSchema and SqlServerCe, but I don't know enough about it to be sure what the deal is.

Comment: Ahhh - if that's the case then no, not much we can do about that. HOWEVER this is a driver-level thing, so if there's a newer driver about that supports this, then hurrah. Sorry for the stray info - I'll correct our site.